# Why does Settings.Default keep adding folders to my "Local Settings\Application Data" folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, settings

I've been using Settings.Default in my application to save user settings for some months now.

Just took a look at my Application Data folder

(i.e. C:\Documents and Settings\MyUserName\Local Settings\Application Data\MyCompanyName)

for the first time, and was surprised to find dozens of entries similar to:

MyProgramName.exe_Url_1hpeczh3uxavwlktuhu4gf0ymjpplavp,
MyProgramName.exe_Url_3klmk1453l42hzqlnufxnlv0ffjvgqih,
etc.

Other, commercial programs just have a simple, obvious directory name (e.g. Adobe\Acrobat).

Can someone explain why this might be happening, and how to fix it?